# aria2 : Are there any plugin I can use with aria2 itergrate with chrome or firefox?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, downloads

I have researched the whole day but it seems there are no good plugins that work well with chrome.

I tried these plugins:

- [Aria2c Integration](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/aria2c-integration/edcakfpjaobkpdfpicldlccdffkhpbfk)
- [YAAW](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/yaaw/hbjpfaalboebibgfmedmjijhbjapcnki)

But it seems they do not work well. When I Right-Click and choose download it does not show inprocess downloading.

I need such a plugin because I need to download a file that I had logged in like on the `drive.google.com site`.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this web ui. This basically by Javascript and connect to aria2 by 6800 port

[Webui-aria2 by ziahamza](https://github.com/ziahamza/webui-aria2)

After downloading to use it do following

1. run command

aria2c --enable-rpc=true -D --check-certificate=false --rpc-allow-origin-all=true --rpc-listen-all=true -s 10 -x 10 -k 1M

- -s : min connection each server/host
- -x : max connection each server/host
- -k : min-split-size

  2. extract downloaded files and run index.html
  3. enjoy your download manager.